# why does my nltk.pos_tag tag letter rather than words

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm new in nltk. I tried to use nltk.pos_tag to tag words like this:[[('This', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('text', 'NN'), ('for', 'IN'), ('test', 'NN'), ('.', '.')], [('And', 'CC'), ('I', 'PRP'), ('want', 'VBP'), ('to', 'TO'), ('learn', 'VB'), ('how', 'WRB'), ('to', 'TO'), ('use', 'VB'), ('nltk', 'NN'), ('.', '.')]]
I followed the instruction and I found a lot of people have got the right result. my code as follows:
    sentences="Why TCP is more reliable than UDP "
    words=nltk.word_tokenize(sentences)
    print(words)
    tags=[]
    for i in range(0,len(words)):
        tags.append(nltk.pos_tag(words[i]))
    print(tags)
however, my result is:

['Why', 'TCP', 'is', 'more', 'reliable', 'than', 'UDP']
[[('W', 'NNP'), ('h', 'NN'), ('y', 'NN')], [('T', 'NNP'), ('C', 'NNP').....

I really wish some genius could help me.

Comment: Try `from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag; pos_tag(word_tokenize('this is a foo bar sentence.')`

Comment: Please replace all images with text content, or your question cannot be answered.